# How often do new contracts appear in the TF2 gunmettle update?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It saids it on the tin, how often do new contracts appear if you've purchased the coin in the new Team Fortress 2 Gunmettle update?

Comment: Suffice to say: every week we'll get two. The extra third one we all got this week was because Valve forgot to put the gunmettle cases/crates into circulation, so they gave us all an extra contract to earn a crate

Comment: @Robotnik Does it change for everyone on a certain day each week or is it a week from when you bought the coin?

Comment: @sommerjj - Probably a week from when Gunmettle was released - so Thursday or Friday depending on where you live.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. Take a look at the [FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/gunmettle/faq/).

> Purchasing access to the campaign will automatically put a Campaign Pass in your inventory that, when activated, converts into a Contract Coin and officially makes you eligible to receive contracts. Participating **gives you access to two contracts a week for the duration of the campaign** that, when completed, will earn you campaign-exclusive weapons and unlockable weapons cases.

You'll get two contracts per week.